# Is singleton class of an object already created?

Tags: ruby, object-model

I would like to know is there any ways to check is singleton class of an 
object already created?

ex: obj.singleton_class_defined?

Comment: @egarcia Excellent point. I love helping people but it's a bit annoying when someone asks for help and then ignores the hard work people put into helping them. It's rude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The singleton class of an object is always defined. In 1.8.7 you can use `singleton_methods` to see if an object already has associated singleton methods:

```
>> foo = ''
=> ""
>> foo.singleton_methods
=> []
```

1.9.2 (possibly also earlier 1.9s, I can't remember) also has a method called `singleton_class`, which saves you from doing the `class << self; self ; end` thing we all got used to:

```
>> foo.singleton_class #=> #<Class:#<String:0x00000100ba5648>>
```

**Edit:**

Since you tagged this with "object-model", I also wanted to recommend the following link:

http://www.hokstad.com/ruby-object-model.html

To quote from there:

> A meta-class is for all practical
>   purposes an actual class. It is an
>   object of type Class. The only thing
>   "special" about a meta-class is that
>   it is created as needed and inserted
>   in the inheritance chain before the
>   objects "real" class. So inside the
>   MRI interpreter object->klass can
>   refer to a meta-class, that has a
>   pointer named "super" that refers to
>   the next class in the chain. When you
>   call object.class in MRI, the
>   interpreter actually "skips" over the
>   meta-class (and modules) if it's
>   there.

Comment: Sure, singleton class always return an object of type Class, and it  inserted in the inheritance chain before the objects "real" class. But I would like to generate a diagram of an object's ancestors, if the object has used singleton class, then it will show in diagram, but it doesn't if object hasn't used singleton class yet.

Comment: Then just check `obj.singleton_methods.empty?` :)

Comment: This answer is incorrect. A singleton class is not always defined, except in the case of classes. In the case of T_OBJECTs the singleton class is created lazily when the singleton class is needed.

Comment: @banister: Yes, formulated sloppily on my part. The snippet I quoted from Hokstad's article says " The only thing "special" about a meta-class is that it is created as needed and inserted in the inheritance chain before the objects "real" class". I guess what I meant is "the class will always be there when you need".